# No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 30.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed the build tools from the Android Studio SDK like that: Tools -> SDK Manager -> Android SDK -> Android 10,11,12 in the SDK Platforms, and Adnroid SDK Build-Tools 32-rc1 in the SDK Tools tab (and a few more packages there).

And when I try to build the project I got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 30.0.3 or higher.
```

In the `~/Library/Android/sdk/` I got the build-tools directory, and there I got: `31.0.0     32.0.0-rc1` dirs.

I have also added this in the PATH:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

It all used to work until Android 12.

What am I missing? Why is it so hard to make the Android work?

Comment: In your app's build.gradle file, please try mentioning version explicitly like android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"}

Answer (score 46):

For me it was just because I could not find the tab in the android studio on where to install build tools. It is actually called SDK Tools under the SDK Manager.

1. [Click on SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkpjI.png)
2. Click from the first tab SDK Platforms to SDK Tools.
3. [SDK Tools and click on show package details and install 31.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewbs2.png)

or

1. Click on File > Settings `CTRL + ALT + S` > Appearance & Behavior
2. [SDK Tools and click on show package details and install 31.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewbs2.png)

Comment: For those can't see versions of Build-Tools in step 3: that list of versions won't show unless you have ticked "Show Package Details".

Comment: Waw : took me a long time to figure it out! I think "Show Package Details" should be changed to something like "Show Other Versions"...

Comment: But its already installed for me and still got this error message...

Comment: Man, I just wasted a couple of hours on this. I wish Android Studio were a little easier to use!

Comment: I want to give you a hug. I wasted hours on Ubuntu and Windows trying to get either environment to work only to realize I was installing from "SDK Platforms" tab instead of "SDK Tools" tab. THANK YOU for your clear instructions. It helps simpletons like me!

Answer (score 19):

Install (beside 32.0.0) 31.0.0 and 30.0.3 versions in the folder ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools (Android Studio -> tools -> SDK manager -> SDK Tools -> Show packages details and select needed versions).

Comment: worked for me, thanks

Comment: Thanks for that - checking "show package details" bottom right opens up options underneath "Android SDK Build-Tools 33-rc2" - I could uncheck all version later than 30.0.3 and check that version. When Cordova reports "No build tools found.Install the Android build tools version 30.0.3 or higher." It actually means 30.0.3 and NO higher!

Answer (score 8):

If you cannot install the specific version 30.0.3 in Android Studio, maybe you can try to use the command tool sdkmanager, run it in terminal as below

```
sdkmanager --sdk_root=/mnt/d/opt/Android/sdk "build-tools;30.0.3"
```

Answer (score 6):

The following procedure given in the below link helped me to solve the problem after trying all the solutions given [here][1]:

Following are the easy steps

1. Open Android studio
2. Click the "More Actions" given under the Welcome window in small blue letters.
3. Click on SDK Manager.
4. Select the SDK Tools (middle) tab
5. Look at the bottom above OK button "show package details" and click
   on the square button to make a tick to select that option.
   Now the package details will be listed.
6. Select the specific version of the required Android-SDK-build-Tools.
7. Click OK to install and then click the finish button.
8. Now restart your developer application and try to build to get success.

Answer (score 3):

When they say:

> Install the Android build tools version 30.0.3 or higher.

They mean **exactly 30.0.3 and not higher**

Try installing exactly that version like @Valentoros answer

Comment: Yep, that worked for me. I had versions 32 and 33 but not 30.0.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

write the correct "Environment Variables".

```
setx ANDROID_SDK_ROOT "C:\android-sdk-windows"
setx PATH "%PATH%;%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools;%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platform- 
tools"
```